Una variable no funciona con Google Custom Search API
Este script genera URLs con búsquedas predefinidas en base a un archivo, y cuando integro la API de Google Custom Search para saber el numero de resultados de cada búsqueda, no se me imprime la variable $ndresultados.
Al final, el problema está en la función "generadorDorks"
He intentado en la misma función y después de que la respuesta de la llamada a la API almacene el valor del numero de resultados a definir un $urlencoded especifico, y solo así funciona:
Captura de pantalla del código sin funcionar
Captura de pantalla del código con un valor establecido
Usando el código de la 2º captura me funciona, pero el 1º no
Para que podáis hacer pruebas, deberéis tener el siguiente archivo:
#!/bin/bash
# shellcheck disable=all
# Google Custom Search API: AIzaSyBzQvAP6r07***************
# cx=a5ab1********************

# ==== VARIABLES GLOBALES ====

clr='\033[0m'
red='\033[00;31m'
green='\033[00;32m'
yellow='\033[00;33m'
blue='\033[00;34m'

nombrearchivo="listadedorks"
nombrearchivobak="listadedorks.bkp"

valorcx="a5ab1********************"
gcs_apikey="AIzaSyBzQvAP6r07***************"

# ==== FUNCIONES ====

function asciiart() # Imprime un assciiart como cabezera del script
{
    echo -e "$red
        
        
            ▓█████▄  ▒█████   ██▀███   ██ ▄█▀  ██████   ▄████ ▓█████  ███▄    █ 
            ▒██▀ ██▌▒██▒  ██▒▓██ ▒ ██▒ ██▄█▒ ▒██    ▒  ██▒ ▀█▒▓█   ▀  ██ ▀█   █ 
            ░██   █▌▒██░  ██▒▓██ ░▄█ ▒▓███▄░ ░ ▓██▄   ▒██░▄▄▄░▒███   ▓██  ▀█ ██▒
            ░▓█▄   ▌▒██   ██░▒██▀▀█▄  ▓██ █▄   ▒   ██▒░▓█  ██▓▒▓█  ▄ ▓██▒  ▐▌██▒
            ░▒████▓ ░ ████▓▒░░██▓ ▒██▒▒██▒ █▄▒██████▒▒░▒▓███▀▒░▒████▒▒██░   ▓██░
             ▒▒▓  ▒ ░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░▒ ▒▒ ▓▒▒ ▒▓▒ ▒ ░ ░▒   ▒ ░░ ▒░ ░░ ▒░   ▒ ▒ 
             ░ ▒  ▒   ░ ▒ ▒░   ░▒ ░ ▒░░ ░▒ ▒░░ ░▒  ░ ░  ░   ░  ░ ░  ░░ ░░   ░ ▒░
             ░ ░  ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒    ░░   ░ ░ ░░ ░ ░  ░  ░  ░ ░   ░    ░      ░   ░ ░ 
               ░        ░ ░     ░     ░  ░         ░        ░    ░  ░         ░ 
             ░                                                                  

                                                                         
                                         "$clr"Created by IaaS365 for iSecurity365
    "
}

function integridad() # Comprueba que existen los archivos con los dorks, si no existen, los crea
{
    echo "[*] Comprobando archivos..."
    base64archivo="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"
    if [ ! -f "$nombrearchivo" ];
    then
        echo "[-] Archivo $nombrearchivo no encontrado. Recuperando el archivo..."
        echo "$base64archivo" | base64 -d > $nombrearchivo
        if [ ! -f "$nombrearchivobak" ];
        then
            echo "[-] Archivo $nombrearchivobak no encontrado. Recuperando el archivo..."
        echo "$base64archivo" | base64 -d > $nombrearchivobak
        fi
    elif [ ! -f "$nombrearchivobak" ]; 
    then
        echo "[-] Archivo $nombrearchivobak no encontrado. Recuperando el archivo..."
        echo "$base64archivo" | base64 -d > $nombrearchivobak
    else
        echo "[i] Todos los archivos se han encontrado"
    fi
}

function generadorDorks() # Genera e imprime dorks, además de imprimir el nº de resultados de la busqueda que genera
{
    #https://www.google.com/search?q=

    while IFS=",,,," read -r descripcion payloadinicial
    do
        payload=$(echo $payloadinicial | cut -c 4-)
        urlencoded=$(echo $payload | sed -e 's/%/%25/g' -e 's/ /%20/g' -e 's/!/%21/g' -e 's/"/%22/g' -e 's/#/%23/g' -e 's/\$/%24/g' -e 's/\&/%26/g' -e 's/'\''/%27/g' -e 's/(/%28/g' -e 's/)/%29/g' -e 's/\*/%2a/g' -e 's/+/%2b/g' -e 's/,/%2c/g' -e 's/-/%2d/g' -e 's/\./%2e/g' -e 's/\//%2f/g' -e 's/:/%3a/g' -e 's/;/%3b/g' -e 's//%3e/g' -e 's/?/%3f/g' -e 's/@/%40/g' -e 's/\[/%5b/g' -e 's/\\/%5c/g' -e 's/\]/%5d/g' -e 's/\^/%5e/g' -e 's/_/%5f/g' -e 's/`/%60/g' -e 's/{/%7b/g' -e 's/|/%7c/g' -e 's/}/%7d/g' -e 's/~/%7e/g')
        url="https://www.google.com/search?q=$urlencoded"
        ndresultados=$(curl -s \
                "https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cx=$valorcx&q=$urlencoded&key=$gcs_apikey" \
                --header "Accept: application/json" \
                --compressed | jq -r ".searchInformation.totalResults")

        echo -e "$green"► $ndresultados - $descripcion"$clr =====> $url"
        echo "$descripcion =====> $url" >> $dominio.dorks.url
    done < $dominio.dorks
    
}

function formateoArchivo() # Modifica el archivo de dorks modificando la plantilla por el dominio concreto
{
    cat $nombrearchivo | sed "s/ejemplo\.com/$dominio/g" > $dominio.dorks
}

# ==== CODIGO ====

case $1 in
    "-e")
    asciiart
    echo -e "[*] Opción eliminar archivos seleccionada"
    rm -f *.dorks *.url
    echo -e "[+] Se han eliminado todos los archivos"
    exit 0
    ;;
    *) 
    asciiart
    integridad
    read -p "[+] Introduce el dominio: " dominio
    formateoArchivo
    generadorDorks
    ;;
esac


